# VWStyles.xml default view style

Tags: list

Of the 14 view styles in VWStyles.XML, which is the default view style used for lists?

Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any of the view styles are the default for a list. The default view for a list is generally located in the schema.xml for the list and most of the time the view doesn't specify a view style.

Answer (score 0):

Under the section **Add CAML for a View Style in VWSTYLES.XML** of the following link, there is a definitive guide on this file. I recommend you read everything from this point on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583132(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If you are using SharePoint 2010.  Else, you will need to check in the Views node of the schema.xml of each list template.